# Preset currency value on select codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a select box with currency 1 and 2, currency 1 is for Euro. I want my select box to preset the value 1 which is euro.

I am using controller to get the currency information like this.

```
$data =  array(
            'sexList' => $this->localization->getTextParamValues(null, 'user', 'Sex'),
            'countryList' => $this->localization->getCountryList(),
            'currencyList' => $this->localization->getCurrencyList(),
            'languageList' => $this->localization->getLanguageList(),
            'user' => $userExist,
            'userinfo' => $this->user_profile->getUserInfo(),
            'Currency' => $this->localization->getCompanyCurrency()
        );

        $this->load->view('header', $this->history->getPreviousPageInArray());
        $this->load->view('borrow_registerpage_view',$data);
```

The currency is pushing the value one to the data array, but in the html file it doesnt preset automatically. Dont know what is wrong.

Here is the HTML code, I need to preset the value 1 in this table so it selects 1 normally which is EURO.

```
<?php   
  echo '<select name="currency_select" id="my_profile_select_currency" class="form-control country_style">';    
    if(!($user['Currency'] > 0)){
       echo '<option value="0">'.lang("myprofile_pinfo_no_currency_set").'</option>';
          foreach ($currencyList as $currency){
             echo '<option value="' . $currency->ID. '">' . $currency->Name . '</option>';
               }
          }else{
                              foreach ($currencyList as $currency){
                                  echo '<option value="' . $currency->ID. '"';
                                  if($currency->ID==$user['Currency']){
                                      echo 'selected';
                                  }
                                  echo '>' . $currency->Name .'';       
                              echo  '</option>';            
                              }
                      }         
                      echo '</select>'  
                      ?>
```

Comment: how many currencies in this table? Are you trying to show first currency as selected?

Comment: There are 2 values, 1 for euro  and 2 for USD 
I am trying to reselect 1 which will show currency name EURO @RejoanulAlam

Comment: so you may use name of currency direct. `$currency->Name == 'EURO' ? 'selected="yes" : ''`

Comment: in which place do I use your code? @RejoanulAlam

Comment: Is you want this in both case? if `$user['Currency']` not zero

Answer (score 0):

**You Need to change your view**

```
$opt = array();
foreach ($currencyList as $currency){
       $opt[$currency->ID] = $currency->Name;
}

echo form_dropdown('currency_select', $opt, set_value('currency_select', $user['Currency'], 'id="my_profile_select_currency" class="form-control country_style"');
```

Comment: I tried it but it still did not work, is it possible you could help me replace my code?

Comment: Have you checked the value of $user['Currency'] ?

Comment: Yea its 1, when I echo it

Comment: if $currency->ID is also 1 then it will be selected

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will show `EURO` selected only if  `$user['Currency']` is greater than `0`

```
   <?php   
    echo '<select name="currency_select" id="my_profile_select_currency" class="form-control country_style">';    
    if(!($user['Currency'] > 0)){
       echo '<option value="0">'.lang("myprofile_pinfo_no_currency_set").'</option>';
          foreach ($currencyList as $currency){
                    echo '<option value="' . $currency->ID. '">' . $currency->Name . '</option>';
               }
          }else{
            foreach ($currencyList as $currency){
                    echo '<option value="' . $currency->ID. '"  '.$currency->Name == 'EURO' ? 'selected="yes"' : ''.'>' .$currency->Name. '</option>';
                  }
              }         
        echo '</select>'  
    ?>
```

If you need in both case you may use `$currency->Name == 'EURO' ? 'selected="yes"' : ''` in both `foreach`